# How to autorefresh chromeDriver with Selenium?

Tags: selenium, refresh

Previously I have been using chrome Auto Refresh plug in. However, now my code has multiple ChromeDriver instances opening and closing and I cannot use Auto Refresh. Also, it is quite a hassle to install Auto Refresh on new computers.

Is there any way to refresh driver  (simulate F5 say every 15 seconds if driver does not change remains motionless) with Selenium similar to Google Auto Refresh?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

refresh is a built in command.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.refresh()
```

If you don't have the chrome driver it can be found here:
https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Put the binary in the same folder as the python script you're writing. (Or add it to the path or whatever, more information here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)

edit:

If you want to refresh ever 10 seconds or something, just wrap the refresh line with a loop and a delay. For example:

```
import time
while(True):
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(refresh_time_in_seconds)
```

If you only want to refresh if the page hasn't changed in the meantime, keep track of the page that you're on. `driver.current_url` is the url of the current page. So putting it all together it would be:

```
import time
refresh_time_in_seconds = 15
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
url = driver.current_url
while(True):
    if url == driver.current_url:
        driver.refresh()
    url = driver.current_url
    time.sleep(refresh_time_in_seconds)
```

Comment: Thank you very much +1. But how can I make it autorefresh every 15 seconds ONLY in case the webpage does not change its Url, i.e. stays motionless

Answer (score 4):

Well there are two ways of doing this.
1. We can use refresh method

driver.get("some website url");
   driver.navigate().refresh();

1. We can use actions class and mimic F5 press

   Actions act = new Actions(driver);
   act.SendKeys(Keys.F5).perform();

Comment: Thank you very much +1. But how can I make it autorefresh every 15 seconds ONLY in case the webpage does not change its Url, i.e. stays motionless

Comment: Hmm how many times you wish to do this? Will you work on only one page?

Answer (score 1):

If you write unit tests that must be run like if you had to open/refresh a new browser session each time, you can use a method with before annotations:

```
@Before
public void refreshPage() {
    driver.navigate().refresh();
}
```

If all tests are individually successful (green) but fail all together, the reason might also been that you need to wait for some resources to be available on the page, so you also need to handle it, setting the timeout like this:

```
public WebElement getSaveButton() {
    return findDynamicElementByXPath(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"form:btnSave\"]"), 320);
}
```

320 is a long time, but you must make sure that you give enough time to get all that it takes to test.